# Model binding to local scope. Change and init manipulate real model

Tags: angularjs, angularfire, angular-material

I really want to bind my checkbox to my model, but i haven't found a good way of doing this, since i have custom logic in the model.

I ended up binding to a fake/local scope variable and then updating the model on ng-change. I set the initial value of the checkbox with ng-init like this:

```
<td ng-repeat="date in dates">
<md-checkbox ng-model="cb.state" aria-label="{{date.txt}}"
ng-change="saveState(person, date, cb.state)" 
ng-init="cb = getState(person, date);" ></md-checkbox>{{date.persons.length }}
</td>
```

In short - the reason i can't just bind the model to the checkbox is because it reflect if this person's key is **NOT** in an array on the date object. My getState and saveState below:

```
$scope.saveState = function(person, date, state) {
    var index = date.persons.indexOf(person.name);

    if (state && index >= 0) {
        date.persons.splice(index, 1);
    } else if (!state && index < 0) {
        date.persons.push(person.name);
    }

    dates.$save(date);
};

$scope.getState = function(person, date) {
    return { state : date.persons.indexOf(person.name) < 0 };
};
```

This actually works, which is great. The problem comes when another client updates the model. When my model is changed, the view is changed too. I actually get the updated new length of the persons array (that is why i put it in the example) - the `{{ date.persons.length }}` is updated. My checkbox on the other hand is not updated - which is kinda obvious since ng-init won't be called again (it only gets called on first init) and my ng-change isn't called either - it's only called when the checkbox itself is changed/clicked.

I'm trying to figure out what the best approach is but can't make up my mind. I have a working solution to trigger a full recreation of the grid (mind you this `ng-repeat` is for only one person - i have a list of dates for a list of persons = big grid) like this:

```
dates.$watch(function (eventData) {
  dates = $scope.dates = $firebaseArray(fb.child("dates"));
});
```

It will flicker the screen because of all the data to update - i'm also concerned what will happen if the user on one client is updating the grid when this event arrives to update the whole thing.

Another solution i'm pondering will check the eventData to figure out what date was changed, then find all checkboxes for this date (one for each person) and manually trigger a change event (possibly using `jqlite` built in angular through `element`). That solution however screams 'wrong' to me since these dom operations go against the declaritiveness of angular.

What do you guys think would be best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a solution watching for changes, but only updating the affected date. This still updates all persons in the list but atleast it only does so for one date.

```
_dates.$watch(function (eventData) {
  var record = _dates.$getRecord(eventData.key)
  if (!record)
    return;

  var index = _dates.indexOf(record);
  _dates[index] = angular.copy(record);
});
```

I'll leave the question/answers open for a while to see if anyone can come up with a better solution.

Don't mind the 'new' _dates variable - i did some refactoring and moved it into a service.